# Proverb meaning "to give something to somebody who does not recognize its value"

Tags: proverb-requests

Can you please tell me an English proverb which means "to give something to somebody who does not recognize the value of that thing"?

Answer (score 26):

Depending on the language level you're looking for. From the bible,

> to cast pearls before swine

"To give things of value to those who will not understand or appreciate it."

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cast_pearls_before_swine

If you need something as valid but more common

> Giving him this gift is simply a waste/ [it's wasted on him/her/me](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wasted-on-sb)

(Cambridge)

Comment: 'Throw pearls before pigs'" is a variant, what means *give someone else something they don't deserve or appreciate*.

Comment: 'On October 14, 1938 the Hartford Courant printed the celebrity gossip column of Sheilah Graham containing this tale:

_Dorothy Parker tells me of the last time she encountered Playwright Clare Boothe. The two ladies were trying to get out of a doorway at the same time. Clare drew back and cracked, “Age before beauty, Miss Parker.” As Dotty swept out, she turned to the other guests and said. “Pearls before swine.”_'
http://quoteinvestigator.com/2011/06/29/pearls-before-swine/

(Doesn't really help with the question - which is why it's a comment not an answer - but it's always cracked me up.)

Comment: The equivalent in India would be - "a donkey doesn't know about the fragrance of camphor"

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Hmm, that is interesting ! In my native language ( Georgian ) we have the same kind of idiom - " a donkey does not know what kind of fruit persimmon is ".

Answer (score 0):

Consider, [***caviar(e) to the general***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/caviare+to+the+general)

> caviar to the general: something of an exceptionally high quality or intelligence not befitting or appreciated by those who consume, see, or partake in it. "General" here refers to the general population, not a military general. *I wrote several novels earlier in my career that were very well received by academics, but they were caviar to the general and never achieved popular success*.

[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/caviar+to+the+general)

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about english, maybe you have something equivalent, but in french we have a proverb which is "To give jam to pigs".